# how to hide modal with jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

button

```
<button type="button" class="btn" onclick="CountClass()" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inlineForm1">OPEN</button>
```

modal

```
<div class="modal fade text-left" id="inlineForm1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel34" aria-hidden="true">
some code
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function CountClass() {
   if(some code){
      $('#inlineForm1').modal('hide');
   }
}
```

why is not it working??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what your `if` expression needs to be, so I'm not addressing that, but to hide something with jQuery you can just use `.hide()` on the element you select.

`$('#inlineForm1').hide();`

Behind the scenes, this adds `style="display:none"` to the element, and the opposite, `.show()` removes this. Knowing this, you can also override the behavior with CSS or start it in one state or the other.

Comment: The if doesn't matter!                                                                              function CountClass() {

$('#inlineForm1').modal('hide');
}                                                                                                  It doesn't work that way either

Comment: Why are you adding the .modal('hide') though? Why not just do .hide()

Comment: function CountClass() {
                                                $('#inlineForm1').hide();
                                               
                                            } not work

Comment: This does not solve the problem. It does not refer to the function

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```